# MySQL Optimization For Large Tables

Tags: mysql, optimization

I can add more details if needed but basically coming into issues with querying large tables (100 million + rows). My queries are taking minutes to complete. Most of the data is previous data (i.e. last year sales data) that will not change. I have used this data in other reports I have made and been able to “roll up” the data on a nightly basis into a new table grouped by month, year, etc. However, wilh the report I am building, there are many dynamic elements, such as custom time/date pickers, that make it hard for me to do such roll up.

I guess my question is, does anyone have much experience with large tables and dynamic queries?

I have done my research as well from what I can and I have also made sure my database is well equipped. Currently 16gb ram and 12gb InnoDB buffer pool. (I am not an expert here, so let me know if there are other things to look for).

Thanks anyone for the assistance, and again, please let me know if you would like specific info on my use case.

```
SELECT   mainaccounts.account_id AS 'ACCOUNTID', 
     ( 
            SELECT name 
            FROM   activitysettings 
            WHERE  org_id = '5a1da86ed6ea7c6000e45e82' 
            AND    id = '5a1da86ed6ea7c6000e45e8e' ) AS 'ACTIVITYNAME', 
     ( 
              SELECT   Count(DISTINCT a.id) 
              FROM     activity a 
              WHERE    a.org_id = '5a1da86ed6ea7c6000e45e82' 
              AND      ( 
                                a.started_at BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND      '2018-02-01') 
              AND      a.status = true 
              AND      a.account_id = mainaccounts.account_id 
              GROUP BY a.account_id ) AS 'ACTIVITYTHIS', 
     ( 
              SELECT   Count(DISTINCT b.id) 
              FROM     activity b 
              WHERE    b.org_id = '5a1da86ed6ea7c6000e45e82' 
              AND      ( 
                                b.started_at BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND      '2017-02-01') 
              AND      b.status = true 
              AND      b.account_id = mainaccounts.account_id 
              AND      b.activity_id = '5a1da86ed6ea7c6000e45e8e' 
              GROUP BY b.account_id ) AS 'ACTIVITYLAST', 
     ifnull( 
     ( 
              SELECT   Sum(s1.volumece) 
              FROM     sales s1 
              WHERE    s1.org_id = '5a1da86ed6ea7c6000e45e82' 
              AND      ( 
                                s1.invoice_date BETWEEN '2018-01-01'AND      '2018-02-01' 
                       AND      s1.status = true 
                       AND      s1.account_id = mainaccounts.account_id group BY s1.account_id ),
                       0) AS 'SALESTHIS', ifnull( 
     ( 
              SELECT   sum(s2.volumece) 
              FROM     sales s2 
              WHERE    s2.org_id = '5a1da86ed6ea7c6000e45e82' 
              AND      ( 
                                s2.invoice_date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND      '2017-02-01' 
                       AND      s2.status = TRUE 
                       AND      s2.account_id = mainaccounts.account_id GROUP BY s2.account_id ),
                       0) AS 'SALESLAST', @podthis := ifnull( 
     ( 
              SELECT   sum(s1.units) 
              FROM     sales s1 
              WHERE    s1.org_id = '5a1da86ed6ea7c6000e45e82' 
              AND      ( 
                                s1.invoice_date BETWEEN '2018-01-01'AND      '2018-02-01' 
                       AND      s1.status = TRUE 
                       AND      s1.account_id = mainaccounts.account_id GROUP BY s1.account_id ),
                       0) AS 'UNITSTHIS', @podlast :=ifnull( 
     ( 
              SELECT   sum(s2.units) 
              FROM     sales s2 
              WHERE    s2.org_id = '5a1da86ed6ea7c6000e45e82' 
              AND      ( 
                                s2.invoice_date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND      '2017-02-01') 
              AND      s2.status = TRUE 
              AND      s2.account_id = mainaccounts.account_id 
              GROUP BY s2.account_id ),0) AS 'UNITSLAST', 
     CASE 
              WHEN ( 
                                @podthis IS NULL 
                       OR       @podthis <= 0) THEN 0 
              ELSE 1 
     end AS 'ISPODTHIS', 
     CASE 
              WHEN ( 
                                @podlast IS NULL 
                       OR       @podlast <= 0) THEN 0 
              ELSE 1 
     end AS 'ISPODLAST' FROM activity mainaccounts WHERE 
     mainaccounts.org_id = '5a1da86ed6ea7c6000e45e82'
     AND      mainaccounts.started_at BETWEEN '2018-12-01' AND      
     '2018-12-31' 
     AND      mainaccounts.status = TRUE 
     AND      mainaccounts.activity_id = '5a1da86ed6ea7c6000e45e8e' 
    GROUP BY account_id
```

I have quite a few indexes, so please ask if there is a specific one you think needed or would help.

[image: explain]

Comment: We need to see the queries, table/index definitions, and maybe a description of the data in the tables.

Comment: Thank you @TimBiegeleisen. I have updated with one of the queries. It is a basic sales table (id, invoice, units sold, date, etc) but it keys off of my activity table which also specifies the "accounts" to query those sales off of as well.

Comment: Also to note, all of the dates and IDs would be user inputs as well. This is a run for a test run with set parameters.

Comment: Can you also add the `EXPLAIN` output of that query? If you've never done so, simply add explain as the first word before the query.

Comment: Sure @PaulT. I have added. Thank you

Comment: Of the "types" in the EXPLAIN plan, `range` is not very optimal. It is caused by comparing a key field (i.e. primary key, unique, etc.) to a constant such as the hardcoded hashes you use in `WHERE` statements. You can read more [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain-output.html#jointype_range). I personally think you should instead look at ways to use JOINS instead of the subqueries.

Comment: @jeremy. Thank you I will read up on that

Comment: Also, my reasoning for not using joins is that I have year over year comparisons which I have found it difficult to use joins with as one number is X time frame and the other is a different time frame. I also only need specific numbers back so I tried to lessen the data returned by using a sub query

Comment: You may be entering [tag:OLAP] territory here. It's always a trade-off with databases it seems. You either tweak and optimize and try to live with the long run time and server performance degredation, or you invest in the "roll up" technique you described, but in a more powerful way with OLAP so you can truly run these types of business intelligence (BI) queries easily.

Comment: @jeremy I really appreciate the responses. I will do some research there as well!

Answer (score 1):

The rollups should be to the *day*.  That lets any date range work by rolling up the Rollup table.

As for other "dynamic" things, you need to have already build Summary tables that include the possible dynamic columns, and provide 'adequate' indexes on the Summary tables.  And then add some smarts to the UI to pick the appropriate Summary table.

In my experience (several projects doing what you have described), it has always been reasonably easy to pick what columns need to be in Summary tables and even tailor the UI page(s) to direct users at the *available* choices.  Once in a while, a new request comes in; then I whip out new code to summarize the raw data into a new Summary table (or augment an existing one), whip out a UI, and the job is done.

More [*discussion*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables)

Side issues...

- What is `index2` and what datatypes are involved?  I worry about `func` in the Explain.
- Ranges

  started_at BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-02-01'

If the target is a `DATE`, you have 32 days.  If it is a `DATETIME`, you have 31 days plus one second (an extra midnight).  I recommend this pattern; it works for all date types, *and* avoids leap-year (etc) hassles:

```
    started_at >= '2017-01-01'
AND started_at  < '2017-01-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

- Indexes

Does mainaccounts have

```
INDEX(org_id, status, activity_id,  -- in any order
      started_at)   -- after the others
```

That is, have the `=`s first, then the 'range'.

Activity needs

```
INDEX(org_id, status, account_id, activity_id,  -- in any order, then
      started_at)
```